# Minidumps: callstacks in VS2017 and VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, windbg, minidump

I created a minidump using MiniDumpWriteDump with only MiniDumpNormal option and got the following strange behavior:

Opened it in VS2015 and got the following
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/ed74b28305bed673032aa0df768d8000.png]

The same dump in VS2017 looks
[image]

Exe file compiled in VS2015 and creates minidump by itself and both of VS use the same dbghelp.dll file.

Looks like only VS2017 can decrypt callstacks.
Also tried WinDBG, but got no luck with it.

Are there any tools to decrypt callstacks without VS2017?

What could be the reason of such behavior (and ways to fix it)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how VS here related at all ? `_NtWaitForSingleObject@12` - usual system call. nothing strange

Comment: I don't know. That's why I created this question. 
In VS2015 it is the single call in main thread stack, but in VS2017 it has normal callstack with function names and normal depth.

Comment: but you not show your both call stacks for compare. say you can use different optimization in builds (one of builds omit frame pointers), may be got got dumps from different points. or may be symbols search paths not initialized to correct values in one vs. vs - this is only integrated shell - nothing more. of course by default (this can be overwritten) different vc use different cl/link versions, but not think this some affect here

Comment: I opened the same dmp file, so optimization things can't affect the result.

Comment: My windbg  was too old, updated it and now it's ok. 

Only vs2015 problem remaned..

Comment: You only show partial (cropped) pictures. How shall we know what's on the other half of the picture? Also: please give some evidence of how symbols are set up in both studios. Are they configured to download symbols from Microsoft? Are they configured to your project's symbols?